# Read line by line from a socket while still allow a telnet client to terminate using ctrl + c

Tags: java

I have a buffered reader reading from a socket line by line. So this works fine. However this looks pretty low level to me and a telnet client is not able to close the connection sending a ctrl + c. So I am wondering if there is some nicer implementation of a stream reader? I.e. the whole tread and loop could easily be abstracted away and just call lambda functions on read, close and error. Or what is the best practice here?

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    // if readline is null then the client just closed connection
                    // if there is something in the buffer and the clients close the connection
                    //  raadLine returns with anything left in the buffer up until the client left
                    //  and returns a second time with null
                    if (readLine == null) {
                        logger.info("client closed connection");
                        socket.close();
                        disconnectAll();
                        break;
                    } else {
                        for (Listener listener : listeners) {
                            listener.messageReceived(this, readLine);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);

                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        logger.error(e1.getMessage(), e1);
                    } finally {
                        disconnectAll();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: Is your buffered reader just blocking waiting for a new line, even after you send a ctrl+c? You would try using a different read method instead of readline, so you get input as it is available.

Comment: The "telnet client" is the sending side? Ctrl-C wouldn't close the stream, it just usually kills the process. Try Ctrl-D instead.

Comment: Ctrl + D is also not closing the client (at least not on windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your base problem is that sending Ctrl-C doesn't close a stream, Ctrl-D does. Edit: [Ctrl-Z on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/291224/equivalent-to-d-in-bash-for-cmd-exe).

The remainder of the question really belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but here goes.

Firstly, you are closing a socket that was opened outside.

Secondly, you shouldn't create `Thread` objects, but use an `ExecutorService`.

Third, I'd recommend using try-with-resource to ensure everything closes automatically.

Fourth, you can use the read line in your `while` statement instead of using `while(true) - break`.

This gives you something like

```
ExecutorService readerExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
public startReadingSocket(Supplier<Socket> createSocket, Consumer<String> lineHandler, Consumer<Exception> excHandler, Runnable cleanUp) {
    readerExecutor.submit(() -> {
        String readLine;
        try (Socket s = createSocket.get();
             InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isReader)) {
             while (readLine = reader.readLine() != null) {
                 lineHandler.accept(readLine);
             }
             System.out.println("client closed connection.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            excHandler.accept(e);
        } finally {
            cleanUp.run();
        }
    }
}
```

And you can run that via

```
startReadingSocket(() -> new Socket(host, port),
    line -> listeners.forEach(l -> l.messageReceived(this, line)),
    ex -> logger.error(ex.getMessage, ex),
    this::disconnectAll);
```

Now this is Java 8, with previous versions you'd need to create interfaces and anonymous classes for the lambdas.

Comment: thx! I did not even knew about codrereview stackexchange. Youa are totally right, the only thing is Ctrl + D does also not close the connection (at least on windows)

Comment: @KIC You are correct: https://superuser.com/questions/291224/equivalent-to-d-in-bash-for-cmd-exe. I added that to the answer.